# How to convert image which taken by camera (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) to NSData in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

Code that i used:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

following is the function to place image which was taken by using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera in image view:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

Comment: So in the function part  i've to get the the NSDATA value which will be the value of image view

Comment: Just an advice, when comparing objects, do not use the equality operator. Use the `isEqual:` method instead.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh Ok will not repeat it again and please help me to find the solution for my question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
UIImage *img          = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
img                   = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image  = img;
NSData *imageData     = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the NSData for image

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Comment: I've one doubt     UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; is it right or @"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" is this right?

Comment: UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; this is correct .. am not sure about second one .. this code is worked for me

Comment: Either will work just fine. However, i'd advise to use the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` itself, without the string annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert like this,

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

If you want to convert back,

```
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
```